# How to use auto generated refresh token in asp.net core 3.1?

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-core, jwt

In my aspnet core 3.1 project I am using CQRS pattern and JWT authentication, I would like
to implement auto refresh token when token is expired for not every time for user to ask entering username and password, I don't want to store refresh token in db as well.What is the best way to refresh token.

My jwtgenerator class for token and for refresh token.

```
    public class JwtGenerator : IJwtGenerator
    {
        private readonly SymmetricSecurityKey _key;

        public JwtGenerator(IConfiguration config)
        {
            _key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(config.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value));
        }

        public string GenerateToken(int size=32)
        {
            var randomNumber = new byte[size];
            using var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
            rng.GetBytes(randomNumber);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(randomNumber);
        }
        public string CreateToken(User user)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.UserName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.Role.ToString("G").ToLower())
            };

            var creds = new SigningCredentials(_key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);
            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                SigningCredentials = creds
            };
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
            return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
        }
    }
```

My login method looks like:

```
         public async Task<GetToken> Handle(Query request, CancellationToken 
        cancellationToken)
            {
                var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(request.Username);

                if (user == null)
                    throw new UnauhtorizedException("Unauthorized");

                var result = await _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, request.Password,false);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return new GetToken()
                    {
                        Token = _jwtGenerator.CreateToken(user),
                        RefreshToken = _jwtGenerator.GenerateToken(32)
                    };
                }

                throw new UnauhtorizedException("Unauthorized");
            }
```

My startup for configuration jwt and authentication:

```
var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value));
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(opt =>
                {
                    opt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        IssuerSigningKey = key,
                        ValidateAudience = false,
                        ValidateIssuer = false
                    };
                });
```

After login I am getting back correct result:

```
{
    "token": "mytoken",
    "refreshToken": "tha1qH7PTx4PNoVeD7D7h/BmEZfdS42zWxriexePWlg="
}
```

P.S. I did not find any example for CQRS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing there is called [`Resource Owner Password Credential`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.3) in [`OAuth2`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749). It looks like pretty much a minimal implementation to me. You need to have the refresh token value or at least a reference value anchoring the token in your authorization layer. It doesn't have to be a database to store such value, you can have in-memory storage, physical file, or whatever you want. But you need to hold the value to validate later anyway.

Below is the standard communication flow, [specified OAuth2 RFC 6749 documentation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.5), which explains a scenario using refresh token.

> **1.5.  Refresh Token**

> Refresh tokens are credentials used to obtain access tokens.  Refresh
> tokens are issued to the client by the authorization server and are
> used to obtain a new access token when the current access token
> becomes invalid or expires, or to obtain additional access tokens
> with identical or narrower scope (access tokens may have a shorter
> lifetime and fewer permissions than authorized by the resource
> owner).  Issuing a refresh token is optional at the discretion of the
> authorization server.  If the authorization server issues a refresh
> token, it is included when issuing an access token (i.e., step (D) in
> Figure 1).

> A refresh token is a string representing the authorization granted to
> the client by the resource owner.  The string is usually opaque to
> the client.  The token denotes an identifier used to retrieve the authorization information.  Unlike access tokens, refresh tokens are
> intended for use only with authorization servers and are never sent
> to resource servers.

> ```
>  +--------+                                           +---------------+
> ```

```
  |        |--(A)------- Authorization Grant --------->|               |
  |        |                                           |               |
  |        |<-(B)----------- Access Token -------------|               |
  |        |               & Refresh Token             |               |
  |        |                                           |               |
  |        |                            +----------+   |               |
  |        |--(C)---- Access Token ---->|          |   |               |
  |        |                            |          |   |               |
  |        |<-(D)- Protected Resource --| Resource |   | Authorization |
  | Client |                            |  Server  |   |     Server    |
  |        |--(E)---- Access Token ---->|          |   |               |
  |        |                            |          |   |               |
  |        |<-(F)- Invalid Token Error -|          |   |               |
  |        |                            +----------+   |               |
  |        |                                           |               |
  |        |--(G)----------- Refresh Token ----------->|               |
  |        |                                           |               |
  |        |<-(H)----------- Access Token -------------|               |
  +--------+           & Optional Refresh Token        +---------------+
```

> ```
>               Figure 2: Refreshing an Expired Access Token
> ```

> The flow illustrated in Figure 2 includes the following steps:

> (A)  The client requests an access token by authenticating with the
> authorization server and presenting an authorization grant.

> (B)  The authorization server authenticates the client and validates
> the authorization grant, and if valid, issues an access token
> and a refresh token.

> (C)  The client makes a protected resource request to the resource
> server by presenting the access token.

> (D)  The resource server validates the access token, and if valid,
> serves the request.

> (E)  Steps (C) and (D) repeat until the access token expires.  If the
> client knows the access token expired, it skips to step (G);
> otherwise, it makes another protected resource request.

> (F)  Since the access token is invalid, the resource server returns
> an invalid token error.

> (G)  The client requests a new access token by authenticating with
> the authorization server and presenting the refresh token.  The
> client authentication requirements are based on the client type
> and on the authorization server policies.

> (H)  The authorization server authenticates the client and validates
> the refresh token, and if valid, issues a new access token (and,
> optionally, a new refresh token).

This problem is implementation specific where you can have too many options for achieving the best practice in your application level. To that end, I want to say **"stick to the standard"**.